# Canada is not in England

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

If I visit
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/cv/18130
I see that this candidate wants to hear about positions in "Canada, England United Kingdom".

Note there actually is a tiny village called Canada in the county of Hampshire - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wellow,_Hampshire. However I very much doubt that this candidate actually wants to look for software jobs there.

Comment: England is a [mysterious country](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46433/france-is-not-within-30-miles-of-london).

Comment: You're neighbours, there's just a little bit of sea between you two

Comment: Do you know how *huge* Canada is?? It wouldn't surprise me a bit if parts of it were in England!

Comment: You know, there is more than one way to fix this bug...

Comment: Maybe the database is just a bit out of date, and the fact that the ownership of Canada has passed from Engand to the USA has not been recored yet :-)

Comment: looking into... will report back with findings...

Comment: I loved looking at the front page and seeing "Canada is not in England : [status-bydesign]".

Comment: I like how a glance at the title and bold red tag suggest that "It is entirely by design that Canada is not in England".

Comment: @Grace: "It is the opinion of StackOverflow et al., that Canada *is* in England. Evidence to the contrary is highly suspect and likely fabricated."

Answer (score 1):

It seems that our instructions for adding locations could be a little clearer... Careers lets you add multiple locations, but only one at a time. If you were to enter "china, taiwan, uk, usa, australia, canada" in the location field all in one go, our geolocation service would try to resolve that, and would come back with "Canada, England United Kingdom".

Comment: Yeah, it's all the geolocation service. It's very interesting. For example, "England, Germany" maps to "England, Schleswig-Holstein, Germany", which is [a small town](http://www.getamap.net/maps/germany/schleswig-holstein/_england/) in the German state of Schleswig-Holstein. Clearly the geolocation service considers England to be on the same level as a state or province, with the United Kingdom being the country/nation. Which is technically accurate.

The best way to deal with this issue is to fix the instructions to explicitly state that each text box represents a *single* location.

Comment: Yup, I had a few minutes of fun trying different combinations as well... We will further clarify the instructions.