# Careers has some weird definition of 'near'

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, geography

The homepage of the Stack Overflow careers suggest that jobs around ten thousand kilometers away are 'near' me:

[image: 'jobs near Singapore' listing jobs in Berlin]

Distance between Singapore and Berlin:

[image: 10 000 km, as calculated by WolframAlpha]

It *might* be a [feature](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/529894#529894), though a better solution to not finding any employers near me would be to not display anything in this section. Or maybe this is just a glitch in the geolocation database used here.

Comment: Haa, brings back memories of [Careers 1.0](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46433/france-is-not-within-30-miles-of-london) issues. Also, for [no less than my own amusement...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54981/canada-is-not-in-england)

Comment: @GraceNote You should see what they're saying in chat about this: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/529896#529896

Comment: Do you have a German IP address? Looks like our IP geolocation library thinks you're in Germany.

Comment: @DavidFullerton If I refresh a few times the page sometimes suggests a job from Australia, which would be slightly saner. There's also that job from South Africa, which is also nowhere near Germany. But to answer your question, no, I do not have a German IP address, to the best of my knowledge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks! We've tightened this up to look for jobs within a smaller radius. Let us know if you still see unexpected results. You might simply not see "near" jobs at all, if there happen to be none close to Singapore.