# Berlin is more than 30 miles from London

Tags: support, jobs

Suppose I search for candidates with dvcs skills within 30 miles of London. The url for this search appears to be

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/search/results?tags=dvcs&tagmatch=0&loc=London%2C+England+United+Kingdom&range=30&surrounding=true&relocate=true&fulltime=true&contract=true&ideas=true&intern=true&students=0&sort=Distance)

Then I get two results including this candidate:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/cv/19541

This candidate's objective is to find jobs in "Berlin, Berlin Germany". This is clearly not correct.

We found in an earlier question that StackOverflow's geography code uses some approximations that actually mean France is just barely 30 miles from London (or a little piece of it is, anyway). See [France is not within 30 miles of London](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46433/france-is-not-within-30-miles-of-london). I don't think this could be the case here.

Comment: **BUG:** Berlin is more than 30 miles from London but shows up in results. **FIX:** Move Berlin closer to London.

Comment: @mmyers: What makes you think the problem is with Berlin?  I say move London...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that a candidate is willing to work in their hometown even if they are also willing to relocate. That candidate's hometown is London so that's why he shows up in your search.

Comment: Thanks. It would be helpful to indicate this in some way, e.g. by automatically putting the candidate's home town in the location list.

By the way, I do talk to many candidates who have made the decision to move and definitely do not want to work in their home towns. Some have already applied for visas or arranged housing in their new location, and are searching for a position in the new place. You may want to provide an option for such people to delete the home town from their list of acceptable locations.