# Fix the bug in stackoverflow careers which prints the city twice

Tags: bug, cv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Location field spells city name incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36638/location-field-spells-city-name-incorrectly)

When companies view my [Stackoverflow CV](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/edwardtanguay), one of the first things they see is a **GIANT TYPO** under my name:

> Berlin, Berlin Germany

instead of:

> Berlin, Germany

The entry form does not allow me to correct this. I type in "`Berlin, Germany`" and it changes it to "`Berlin, Berlin Germany`". I type in "`Berlin`" and it changes it to "`Berlin, Berlin Germany`".

**How can I correct this or override this so that under my name is simply City, Country?**

Suggestion: allow us to type in "`override: Berlin, Germany`" which overrides the automatic correction causing the problem, or just allow us to click a box which causes the city/country line not to appear. Anything is better than a typo at the top of your CV.

Comment: This is **not a bug**! “Berlin, Berlin, Germany” is the *correct* spelling: The city is Berlin, the federal state is *also* Berlin and the country is Germany. For Munich, the same would read “München, Bayern, Germany”, and this is strictly equivalent. (Furthermore, Berlin is not the only special case, Hamburg and Bremen also form own federal states.)

Comment: Addendum: it seems that for other places (Zürich, Canton of Zürich, and Reykjavik, Reykjavik) it’s not customary to include the region when it has the same name as the city. But I want to emphasize that for German federal states, including the state name *is* the canonical spelling, even if said state name equals the city name. To make this even more confusing, there are cities that have the same name as a federal state but which are *not* identical to the state (take Brandenburg, a (rather small) city in the state Brandenburg).

Comment: "Berlin, Berlin, Germany, Europe, Earth, 52 30 N 13 25 E" is technically not a bug either but you don't want that at the top of your CV.

Answer (score 1):

You can't fix this.

**Why not?**

The location is used by employers to determine your distance from them. For this to be possible, the Careers engine needs to be able to understand where you are. It contracts this service out to the Yahoo API, which is, well, not the [best in the world](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46433/france-is-not-within-30-miles-of-london).

**Related Questions**

[Location field spells city name incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36638/location-field-spells-city-name-incorrectly)

[Why does careers location field change Jyväskylä to Jyvaskyla?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28080/why-does-careers-location-field-change-jyvaskyla-to-jyvaskyla)

[Careers won't let me list Reykjavik, Iceland as location](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24962/careers-wont-let-me-list-reykjavik-iceland-as-location)

Comment: Right, ok, but a quality of a good developer is to be able to see the problem from the customer's point of view. To the customer, that is a **TYPO**. For hundreds of developers to have to explain in interviews that there is a typo on their CV because of [technical problem] and that "it cannot be fixed", is not a good selling point for how they will approach similar problems in the company at which they are interviewing. Of course it can be fixed. If Yahoo API has limitations, then there should be a way to override it so it (a) does not appear, or (b) can be substituted by some text.

Comment: Oh, you can remove it at http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/publish, I was just saying that there's no way for *you* to override what's displayed. Unfortunately, it looks like it only affects the CV, but not what hiring managers see.

Comment: ah ok, I see how you can click it off, thanks, that's good enough, would be nice, though, if there was just a text field where we could write any text for a subtitle